# CentOS 6 in production

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, rhel6

All of my virtual servers are on Centos 5.5. Now I am deploying new one and there is a new OS option: CentOS 6. I like new software, and I prefer to use new versions (but not the edge). So, as far as I am not an administrator and my apps are not highloaded is it a good choice to prefer CentOS 6 to CentOS 5.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, no. CentOS 6 is very much behind RHEL 6.1 and [Scientific Linux 6.1](http://www.scientificlinux.org/news/sl61). See: https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&topic_id=32027&forum=14

The problem here is that the upstream distribution has moved on, so CentOS 6 isn't really a good target platform. I would wait until CentOS 6.1 is available or stick with 5.x.

Edit: One option for CentOS 6 is to leverage the [continuous release repository (CR)](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/CR), which keeps the CentOS 6 point release in sync with RHEL 6.1. It's a slight compromise, but would be another option for continuing to use CentOS.

Comment: Even 5.x is falling behind.  RHEL 5.7 has been out since Jul 21st, and as of today, still no CentOS 5.7.

Comment: @Chadd, that is not true:

[root@centos /]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)

Answer (score 4):

Certainly you should test things, but CentOS 6 is essentially RHEL 6, and RHEL 6 has been in serious production for almost 10 months now (CentOS was slow in getting organized for RHEL 6 for whatever reason).